# Galaxy S6 won't charge after drain to 0-1%, cannot boot

Tags: charging, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-6

After letting my Galaxy S6 drain more than usual, I connected it to the fast charger a bit after it hit 1%, and left it for the night while still powered on.

Next morning the phone was off. Powering it on, the phone shuts down before completing boot.

I plugged it in to an Anker charger, also supporting Quick Charging, and left it all day. Same problem. Once it managed to finish booting, allowing me to catch a glimpse of the 0% battery indicator in the status bar.

I tried booting into recovery mode (holding Vol. Up and Home while pressing Power) and left it to charge for about an hour before rebooting. Same problem.

Any suggestions, please? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the chance to attempt to charge the phone via a wireless Qi-charger which, to my surprise, worked. So it didn't seem to simply be a dead battery, or a weird software loop, but something specifically concerning the USB/charging port.

I decided to bite the bullet and had the phone repaired. They replaced the "Charging Port Flex Cable", a part that can be bought online for 14$ or less, in case you feel like replacing the part yourself.

Answer (score -1):

1. Connect to a charger
2. Wait 30 mins-1 hr
3. Unplug the charger
4. Press and hold the **power key** until you see the Samsung Galaxy logo

Comment: This sounds like what he already did in the question, and he already provided an answer.